# Argument Error with Inherited Class

Tags: ruby

I've defined a class as follows

```
class CraigslistPost < Nokogiri::XML::Element
  def initialize(html)
    if html.class != Nokogiri::XML::Element
      raise 'Must initialize with a Nokogiri XML Element'
    end
    super(html.name,html.document)
  end
```

And when I try to instantiate it I get an argument error.. Why would my new class want 2 arguments? I've only listed one.

```
[4] pry(main)> row.class
=> Nokogiri::XML::Element
[5] pry(main)> CraigslistPost.new(row)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)
```

Even more confusing, when I provide two arguments it says it wants 1.

```
[6] pry(main)> CraigslistPost.new(row.name,row.document)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from lib.rb:24:in `initialize`
[7] pry(main)> CraigslistPost.new(row)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)
from (pry):7:in `new'
```

Comment: Errors referencing actual line numbers would help, especially for solving the 2 for 1 vs 1 for 2+. Have you tried a debugger like byebug to and placing it inside the initialize for CraigslistPost to check for yourself what the html.class is?

Comment: Just to narrow down the issue, if you inherit from a plain Ruby class that takes two arguments in the constructor, instead of from `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, do you get the same result? If so, it may be specific to Nokogiri and its compiled C/Java code. I don't understand the structure of the C/Java code well enough to know for sure, but the comments around https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.7.2/ext/java/nokogiri/XmlNode.java#L309 could relate.

Comment: @Max - I definitely think this is specific to Nokogiri - the code comments in the above link help clarify the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Your class ultimately inherits from the `Nokogiri::XML::Node` class, the `initialize` method of which now requires [two parameters](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#newclass_method). You may want to change the class to this:

```
class CraigslistPost < Nokogiri::XML::Element
  def initialize(html, document)
    if html.class != Nokogiri::XML::Element
     raise 'Must initialize with a Nokogiri XML Element'
    end  
    super(html.name, html.document)
  end  
end
```

and then try something like the following:

```
file = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("path/to/document.xml"))
CraigslistPost.new(row, file)
```

Comment: Sure I could change it this way, but doesn't that defeat the whole point? Why am I not able to just inherit and override the initialize method?